# How to escape dict from str in python?

Tags: python

Come straight to the point.

A str object below:

`s = '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3"}'`

As you see, **dict is wrapped in str**. Now how to **escape dict from str**?

In other words, `is it possible d = operate(s), d["key1"] = "value1"`, and etc?

Comment: `eval()` works perfectly.  But every claims it is a security problem.  Have you looked at `eval()` yet?

Comment: @S.Lott Oh, My fault neglecting this eval() function. Thank you very much, :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> ast.literal_eval('{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3"}')
{'key3': 'value3', 'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'value1'}
```

Comment: nice, but only available in python 2.6 or higher

Comment: Hey, thanks for your tips, but what is the difference between built-in eval() and ast.literal_eval()? Thank you!

Comment: `ast.literal_eval()` will *only* convert strings that look like Python literals; attribute and function calls will be rejected.

Answer (score 3):

i'd use json:

```
try:
   import json
except ImportError:
   import simplejson as json

d = json.loads(s)
```

Comment: Thank you, I handle this problem using json too, eval() function is what i want. Anyway, thanks for your help, :)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [eval](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval).